# Where can I find results of various experiments and studies in fields such as medicine, biology, chemistry, psychology, and so on...?

Tags: research-process

During my statistics class I have encountered some nice studies, some of them having some nice and interesting results. This brought me to this question. One example of such studies is  on http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10229312 , but this is just a summary of the actual experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results of scientific studies are usually published in one of many field-specific peer-reviewed journals. A list of some of these journals, sorted by the discipline can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_scientific_journals). Access to these published data is rarely free. You may need to obtain access through your institution's library. It is also worth being aware that most papers will only include a summary or overview of entire data collection sets, and you can often find deeper analyses and more comprehensive experimental data in the published supplementary information

There are also a number of [open access journals](http://doaj.org/), which, as the name implies, are open access. These may be of interest to you if you are just looking for general sets of experimental data.